# How to reload View after calling JQuery to do action and display message

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I'm trying to figure out a way to reload the table, after each button action. I was thinking of reloading the page, but I don't know how I would reload the page, then print a message returned from the WebService function into the div.

CSHTML code:

```
@model Namespace.Models.ItemModel
<div id="deleted" />
<input text id="curSelId" />
<input text id="curSelObj" />
<input text id="curSelfObjId" />
<table>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.myDeleted)
    {
        <tr id="@item.DeletedId" value="@item.DeletedId">
            <td>@item.Timestamp</td>
            <td class="type">@item.Type</td>
            <td class="typeid">@item.TypeId</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery code:

```
function Undo()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Content("~/webservices/retrieve.asmx/Undo")",
            data: "{'index': '" + $('[id$=curSelId]').val() + "'," +
                  "'type': '" + $('[id$=curSelObj]').val() + "'," +
                  " 'typeId': '" + $('[id$=curSelObjId]').val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

                //http://encosia.com/2009/06/29/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/
                if (msg.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
                    // Leave the .d behind and pass the rest of
                    //  the JSON object forward.
                    var obj = msg.d;
                    $("#deleted").html(obj);
                }
                else {
                    // No .d; no transformation necessary.
                    AjaxSucceeded(msg, dropdown, hidden);
                }
            }
            , error: AjaxFailed
        });
    }
```

Edited: Added input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to reload it would be to use AJAX:

```
@model Namespace.Models.ItemModel
<div id="deleted"></div>
<div id="mytable" data-url="@Url.Action("MyTable", "SomeController")">
    @Html.Partial("_MyTable", Model)
</div>
```

where `_MyTable.cshtml` contains the table:

```
@model Namespace.Models.ItemModel
<table>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.myDeleted)
    {
        <tr id="@item.DeletedId" value="@item.DeletedId">
            <td>@item.Timestamp</td>
            <td class="type">@item.Type</td>
            <td class="typeid">@item.TypeId</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

and inside the success callback of your ajax request reload the div:

```
success: function (msg) {
   var myTableDiv = $('#mytable');
   myTableDiv.load(myTableDiv.data('url'));
   ...
}
```

where the MyTable action would render the same partial:

```
public ActionResult MyTable()
{
    ItemModel model = ...
    return PartialView("_MyTable");    
}
```

Comment: Can I still get values from _MyTable.cshtml if I'm using the ajax from the page calling _MyTable? How do I grab values from a Partial   from the parent page.

Comment: @user759458, what values do you want to grab and where (javascript?)?

Comment: I set up that when I click on the table row, it will fill some input text with info about the row it was clicked on so when I click on the button it will pull the index, type, and typeId (as shown in the ajax call. Added the input fields to code.

Comment: @user759458, so what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that your answer doesn't give me a way to return a message when ajax reloads the page.